# Calling I18n translation method from within a simple_form marked up using haml

Tags: internationalization, haml, translation, simple-form, i18n-gem

I am working with the I18n gem and am just wondering how the translation method can be called while using a haml based simple_form. Current my code is as follows:

**\users\new.html.haml**
    - content_for :title, "Admin | Create New User"
    .page-header
        %h1 Create New User

**/config/localses/en.yml**
    en:
      new_tenant:
        title: "Tenant Administration | Create New Tenant"
        header: "Create New Tenant"

**/config/localses/de.yml**
    de:
      new_tenant:
        title: "Mieter Administration | Create New Mieter"
        header: "Erstellen Neuer Mieter"

I have seen in Railcasts episode 138 that this could be called as follows:

```
<% title t('new_tenant.title') %>
<h2><%= t 'new_tenant.header' %></h2>
```

How can I apply this same method to the haml markup? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
%title=t 'new_tenant.title' 
%h2=t 'new_tenant.header'
```

Sometimes you can't use the i18n shorthand **t**, in those cases just use **I18n.t** instead of the shortcut. Good luck.